# Verify Data in Array Of Objects in Nodejs (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of objects generated from database query using MongoDB Aggregation framework.

```
[ 
  { user_type: 'STUDENT', comments : 25  },
  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 35 },
  { user_type: 'TEACHER', comments: 26 },
  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 41 },
  { user_type: 'PRINCIPAL', comments: 60 },
]
```

the query pipeline of `mongodb` is such that it will return a `user_type` in the array only if any person of that user type have comments on a particular post, if there is no comment from a `user_type` that user type will not feature in the array.

To accomplish a task i need to check if all have commented and if yes show its count, so i need to check if array has atleast one object with each user_type against a list saved locally i.e `PARENT, TEACHER, STUDENT, PRINCIAPL` this list can be changed at will.

EDIT : MY Requirement is that the array of objects must have atleast one object which has a usertype each from a list saved locally.

Clarification : Number of comments here is comments by all users of that type i.e if two teachers have commented 10 comments each then user_type teacher has 20 comments

Comment: `and if yes show its count` so in the example you've provided, would the count would be `187`, `146` (only first `PARENT`) or `152` (only last `PARENT`)?

Comment: For example, you have this list `[TEACHER, STUDENT]` locally, what you want to accomplish is verify that the retrieved array has at least one `TEACHER` and one `STUDENT` object?

Comment: @Ele ...yes it shoudl have atleast one of each usertype

Comment: Closing as "unclear" until you [edit] the question to clearly address the above requests for clarification.

Comment: Your requirement about count is unclear. Please add some more details perhaps some expected output as well.

Comment: number of comments here is comments by all users of that type i.e if two teachers have commented 10 comments each then usetype teacher has 20 comments

Comment: As I said earlier, what is your expected output from above array? If you could show us it will be much better to get what you are willing to achieve.

Comment: @MohammadUsman .....read second comment of by ele he got what i wanted and also gave a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `user_types`(function `map`) from the result of MongoDB and then check if the `user_types` within that local list (filter) are all included (function `every`).

`DUMMY` is not included, so should return `false`.

```js
var filter = ["STUDENT", "DUMMY"];
var array = [  { user_type: 'STUDENT', comments : 25  },  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 35 },  { user_type: 'TEACHER', comments: 26 },  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 41 },  { user_type: 'PRINCIPAL', comments: 60 },];

var mapped = array.map(o => o.user_type),
    result = filter.every((f) => mapped.includes(f));            
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

All `user_types` are included, so should return `true`.

```js
var filter = ["STUDENT", "PRINCIPAL", "TEACHER"];
var array = [  { user_type: 'STUDENT', comments : 25  },  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 35 },  { user_type: 'TEACHER', comments: 26 },  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 41 },  { user_type: 'PRINCIPAL', comments: 60 },];

var mapped = array.map(o => o.user_type),
    result = filter.every((f) => mapped.includes(f));    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks , Your answer was very short and accomplished the task just how i wanted, Thanks for your time , Really Appreciate, it would had taken me days to reach this solution by myself.

Comment: @GauravKumar great!!, you're welcome!! :-)

Comment: can you just tell me in one line what is piece of code in your solution doing >> array.map(o => o.user_type) & specially this part >> o => o.user_type

Comment: @GauravKumar this `array.map(o => o.user_type)` creates a new array with the same length of `array` and with the string `user_type`, i.e: ["STUDENT", "PRINCIPAL", "TEACHER", ....].  Take at look at this documentation [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: ok thanks for the link that's just what i wanted ....i will take care of understanding by myself, well good day

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, you can create an object with properties for each aggregate comment count, given an array of `types`.

```js
function aggregateComments(results = [], types = []) {
  return types.reduce((acc, type) => {
    acc[type] = results.filter(
      ({ user_type }) => user_type === type
    ).reduce((sum, { comments }) => sum + comments, 0);

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const results = [ 
  { user_type: 'STUDENT', comments : 25  },
  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 35 },
  { user_type: 'TEACHER', comments: 26 },
  { user_type: 'PARENT', comments: 41 },
  { user_type: 'PRINCIPAL', comments: 60 },
];
const types = ['STUDENT', 'PARENT', 'TEACHER', 'PRINCIPAL'];

console.log(aggregateComments(results, types));
```

Comment: the solution by ele was short, clear and more understandable for me, so i went on to try that first and it worked like a charm, anyways thank you very much for your time, really appreciate.